# what is the general definition of roughness?

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I have read a paper "Gatheral, Jim, Thibault Jaisson, and Mathieu Rosenbaum. "Volatility is rough." Quantitative Finance 18.6 (2018): 933-949."

In this paper, the authors stated that the volatility is rough. But what is the definition of roughness?

Thanks for your kindly help.